# record deleted while other records are inserted in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have to insert some records inside a MYSQL table. Everything seems to work as it should be, until when I arrive to a point where records are inserted properly but some of the previous inserted records disappear.

I tried dropping e recreating the table, with EasyPHP and WAMP but still the same problem.

Database has a size of 1.1 MB about when the problem arise. 
Collation: UTF8 and latin1_swedish_ci   (I've tried both, but the problem persist)
What could be the cause?
The file that insert records doesn't have any delete, I'm sure, there are only INSERT...

I need help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Code samples would be great. MySQL does not simply delete your data. Either you deleted it accidentally, or you have another application/user playing around with your database (unlikely).

Comment: ...or it only *appears* to you as though they have been deleted, when in fact they are still in the table.

Comment: How is it that you are making the determination that rows have been deleted? I strongly suspect that all of the rows you actually inserted into the table are actually there. I suspect that either some of the INSERTs are not actually inserting a row (rejected by duplicate key exception, or malformed statement?), or the rows did get inserted, and they are there in the table, and it just appears to you that they are not (LIMIT clause on the query?) This question is impossible to answer definitively from the information provided; we can only make guesses.

Comment: Yeah please send code samples, otherwise it can be many reasons.